# How can I encode this URI component in PL/SQL?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis, plsql, urlencode

My Oracle backend procedure needs to encode some encrypted values and pass them to an ASP .NET MVC application through the URL. I already know about `utl_i18n.escape_reference` and `utl_url.escape`, but they don't seem to be able to encode the text in the same way as the ASP.NET application.

The problem is that the + does not get encoded and comes as a space when I debug the ASP.NET application.

The following 3 statements all return '`+`' when I run them in TOAD, whereas I'm expecting "`%2B`":

```
select utl_i18n.escape_reference('+') from dual
select utl_url.escape('+') from dual
select utl_i18n.escape_reference(utl_url.escape('+')) from dual
```

Perhaps it has to do with the character set? How can I check the character set in IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `+` is a reserved character for [`UTL_URL.ESCAPE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_url.htm#i996850); to quote:

> The reserved characters consist of:
>
> - Semi-colon (;) slash (/), question mark (?), colon (:), at sign (@), ampersand (&), equals sign (=), plus sign (+), dollar sign ($),
>     and comma (,)
>
> Many of the reserved characters are used as delimiters in the URL. You
>   should escape characters beyond those listed here by using escape_url.
>   Also, to use the reserved characters in the name-value pairs of the
>   query string of a URL, those characters must be escaped separately.

There is a Boolean parameter `escape_reserved_characters`, which allows you to escape the `+`:

> Indicates whether the URL reserved characters should be escaped. If
>   set to TRUE, both the reserved and illegal URL characters are escaped.
>   Otherwise, only the illegal URL characters are escaped. The default
>   value is FALSE.

You cannot use Boolean's in SQL, so you would have to do this in PL/SQL

```
declare
   l_escaped_url varchar2(10);
begin
   l_escaped_url := utl_url.escape('+', True);
   dbms_output.put_line(l_escaped_url);
end;
/
```

Comment: I am looking for something similar, i want to escape '+' sign but not the other reserved characters. Is there a way to escape certain characters?

Comment: I think you just have to manually `REPLACE()` at that point @Ash.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply! I think I found the solution. It turns out that it doesn't make sense to escape a special character so now I am encoding all the reserved characters.